# Qué método puedo utilizar para eliminar una palabra cualquiera de una frase u oración en Java?

Tags: java

Escriba una clase que permita eliminar un `substring` substr de un string str, si no está devuelve el mismo string sin alterar

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Ejer03 {

    String oracion;
    String palabraEliminar;
    String nuevaOracion;

    public Ejer03() {


    }

    public void palabraEliminar() {//Este metodo supone que debe elegir una palabra para eliminarla de una Frase u oración.

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduzca la Frase u Oración");
        oracion = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca la Palabra que desea Eliminar");
        palabraEliminar = teclado.nextLine();
        nuevaOracion = oracion
        System.out.println(nuevaOracion);

    }

}
```

Comment: `replaceAll`  antes emplear `contains`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar sería validar si el `Substr` está en el `String` principal con el método `contains` si es así , procedemos a reemplazar con `replaceAll` , su función quedaría :

```
 public static String  palabraEliminar(String oracion,String palabra) {
    if(oracion.contains(palabra))
        return oracion.replaceAll(palabra, "");
    return oracion;
}
```

Si no desea tener en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas se cambiaría la linea del `if`

```
if(oracion.toLowerCase().contains(palabra.toLowerCase()))
```

Desde el `main` se llamaría así

```
String oracion = "Hola Mundo";
String palabra = "m";
System.out.println(palabraEliminar(oracion, palabra));
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Joel...

Answer (score 0):

La manera más sencilla partiendo de tu código es sustituir tu línea

`nuevaOracion = oracion;`

por

`nuevaOracion = oracion.replace(palabraEliminar, "");`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Fran Pastor